# Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension returns hidden characters in string

Tags: c#, string, encoding

I have a problem with [`System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If i load a file, the string which is returned by the method contains some hidden chars. In HEX: `3F`.

The follwing pictures contains the problem. See the hex editor:

[image]

The texfiles were created with Notepad++ and the Encoding is `UTF-8 without BOM`.

Maybe some one has a solution, thank you!

Comment: what is the (exact hex) contents of  `path`?

Comment: This is the exact content: `57 69 6B 69 5C 5C 41 72 74 69 63 6C 65  73 5C 5C **3F 3F** 45 72 6C E4 75 74 65 72 75 6E 67 20 76 6F 6E 20 53 69 6E 67 6C 65 74 6F 6E 2E 74 78 74` I've marked the 3F. As string: `Wiki\\Articles\\??Erläuterung von Singleton.txt`

Comment: "Wiki\\Articles\\??Erluterung von Singleton.txt" Already contains your mentioned characters :)

Comment: Result is correct for your given input,, ?? is a part of it

Comment: So you have to search at another place: "Why does path contain these characters?"

Comment: Yep, and the problem seems to be Nodepad++, because the files were created with it. Thank you!

Comment: Should i delete the question?

Comment: @BendEg better reformulate so it reflects the real problem

Answer (score -1):

I created file with Notepad++ v6.6.4 and put the file in debug folder called myFile.txt and the Encoding is "UTF-8 without BOM" and if you apply the next code which read all the text from the original file created above and put all the content in new file in the same directory you will find exactly all the content without any difference.

[image: This is the picture of original file by Notepad++ and new file]

```
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace FilePathWithNotepad__
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string originalFilePath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\myFile.txt";
            string title = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(originalFilePath);
            string content = File.ReadAllText(originalFilePath);
            string newfile = Path.GetFileName(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\new.txt");
            File.WriteAllText(newfile,content);
        }
    }
}
```